# Looping through array with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am trying to make a basic program that loops through an array and logs the 'place' & 'distance' to the console. My program isn't working as intended and won't log the values to the console. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
let destinations = [
  {place: ['Dubai'],
  distance: 7276},
  {place: ['Sydney'],
  distance: 8759},
  {place: ['London'],
  distance: 4166},
  {place: ['tokyo'],
  distance: 5754},
  {place: ['Seoul'],
  distance: 6037},
];

destinations.forEach(spot => {
    if (spot.length < 6) {
      console.log(`${spot} is an interesting vacation spot.
      Let's see how far it is before we pull the trigger`);
      destinations.forEach(howFar => {
        if (howFar < 6000) {
          console.log(`${spot} is close enough. Let's go there!`);
        } if (howFar > 6000) {
          console.log(`Nevermind. ${spot} is too far.`);
        }});
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not how you get the length of a JS object. Does this answer your question? [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: The `spot` is an object (e.g.place: ['Dubai'] distance: 7276) and the length will be undefined

Comment: Have you tried to do `console.log(spot.length)` or read the errors in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to step through the code very carefully to try to see what the JS interpreter sees. It can help to put down the value of variables on scratch paper and how they change as you loop. That'll help you see your own mistakes:

```
destinations.forEach(spot => {
```

What is `spot` here? It'll be each value of `destinations`, so for example on the first iteration it'll be `{place: ['Dubai'],distance: 7276}`.

```
if (spot.length < 6) {
```

What would the `length` property be for `{place: ['Dubai'],distance: 7276}`? That doesn't look like it'd have a `length` property. It's not an Array. Plus, what condition are you checking here? Are you sure you need an if statement here?

```
console.log(`${spot} is an interesting vacation spot.
Let's see how far it is before we pull the trigger`);
```

What would you expect to see putting `spot` in a string here? Its value is `{place: ['Dubai'],distance: 7276}`. Are you sure you're not wanting to get some value from the object to put into the string?

```
destinations.forEach(howFar => {
```

Isn't this looping over the same Array you looped over earlier? Given 6 destinations, this means it'll run 36 times. And what is `howFar`? Since it's from `destinations.forEach`, it'll be one of the objects in the `destinations` array.

```
if (howFar < 6000) {
```

Would an object in the `destinations` array be comparable to a number? It's an object, so that won't work. Did you mean to access the `distance` property of the object?

My first piece of advice is to simplify your `destinations` Array. `place` is an Array of strings currently, but they're all single items, so you probably don't need an Array for that. Also, since you're not changing `destinations`, you could make it a a `const` variable which is helpful because it lets someone looking at your code know they don't have to worry about finding places where it might be changing:

```
const destinations = [
  {place: 'Dubai', distance: 7276},
  {place: 'Sydney', distance: 8759},
  {place: 'London', distance: 4166},
  {place: 'Tokyo', distance: 5754},
  {place: 'Seoul', distance: 6037},
];
```

Your way of looping through the destinations is fine, but you'll need to access the *properties* of the object, and you don't need the extraneous inner loop and if statement (unless you meant to do something with it that I'm not understanding).

```
destinations.forEach(spot => {
  console.log(`${spot.place} is an interesting vacation spot.
    Let's see how far it is before we pull the trigger`);
  if (spot.distance < 6000) {
    console.log(`${spot.place} is close enough. Let's go there!`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Nevermind. ${spot.place} is too far.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I started coding literally a few weeks ago so I'm still green in my understanding of things. I originally had wrote it out as destinations.place.forEach & destinations.distance.forEach which gave me an error so I left the "spot" & "howFar" portions of those loops in there so thats where some of the confusion on my end was. Thanks for explaining this in a way that I was able to understand & learn from. :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Best of luck on your learnings!

Answer (score 1):

You are basically doing an Object.length, wich doesn't exist. Try something like spot.place or spot.distance.

Also, you cannot do a destinations.forEach inside destinations. Is this really necessary?
Try something like this:

```
destinations.forEach(spot => {
if (spot.place.length < 6) {
  console.log(`${spot.place} is an interesting vacation spot.
  Let's see how far it is before we pull the trigger`);
  if (spot.distance < 6000) {
     console.log(`${spot.place} is close enough. Let's go there!`);
  } else {
      console.log(`Nevermind. ${spot.place} is too far.`);
  }
}})
```